# onItemClick on GalleryView

Tags: android

I am displaying multiple images using the Gallery class

I am using the following code to

```
private SampleGallery mGalleryView1 = null;


mGalleryView1 = (SampleGallery) findViewById(R.id.galleryView1);
mGalleryView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

**SampleGallery class extends the Gallery**

The problem I am facing is that , when I am clicking on the images,

from the following method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {}
```

I am getting the position of the image as a no like "13878342720" & not any value like "0" , "1" .

Actually based on the position value , I am doing some logical calculations , so am ending getting the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" , since the position value is returning nothing.

Kindly provide your inputs , why the position is being returned so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the from the following code

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {}
```

in my case , long id is returning me the exact position when I am clicking the images on the gallery.

```
int localPostion = (int) id ;
```

Now, I can use the localPosition & use if for the logical calculations

Answer (score 0):

Seems like following line in your code is causing this

```
private SampleGallery mGalleryView1 = null;
```

this is setting your gallery to `null` and thats why you getting garbage position in your onItemClick listener.

Have you tried adding some elements to it and then clicking on it?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `mGalleryView1` as  `SampleGallery`,but your are tycasting that as `ZoomGallery`.You must declare your `mGalleryView1` as you mention your `galleryView1` in your layout XML.

Comment: @chiranjib: Edits are not used for responding to other people's answers. Leave comments instead.

Comment: I wrongly typed SampleGallery as ZoomGallery . Also , I had included the galleryView1 on the layout xml , still I got that value

Comment: @chiranjib: *-facepalm-* And you don't need to edit saying you're changing the edit to a comment when we've already rejected the previous edit...

Comment: @BoltClock .. I am aware of that , I removed my comment from Edit .. but it showed me an error which asked me to enter something to edit again. I wanted to remove by comment from edit .. it didn't allow me so without adding anything

Comment: looks like you have problem in your adapter.Can you please show the adapter code